Interrupt routine has unexpected execution
An interrupt routine is executing unexpectedly, and I can't figure out why. Can you please have a look?
Hardware is a generic (knock off) Arduino Mega, with an unused Ethernet shield, and a touch screen shield. It looks like so:

I am connecting a flow meter that looks like this:

It has an external pull up resistor, and is wired like so:

and I am using pin 18 as is suggested for the hardware here: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/.
The code is straight forward:
global variable definition:
const byte interruptPin = 18;
volatile unsigned long waterFlowSensorCount= 0;
inside setup():
pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), incrementWaterSensorCount, FALLING);
handler function:
void incrementWaterSensorCount()
 {
  waterFlowSensorCount = waterFlowSensorCount + 1; }
Everything works as it should... until I activate some specific outputs. The 0V and 5V that are powering the flow meter are also the same power source for the relays I am turning on. The moment the relays are turned on, the interrupt routine runs about 15 times. for the sake of full disclosure, the project has several power supplies and looks like so:

I tried all the arguments when defining the interrupt routine (RISING, FALLING, HIGH, LOW) and the behavior is the same, I mean, the flow meter is just sitting there and the count is incrementing (but it 'should' not). The voltage drop on the 5V power supply is negligible. The voltage on the interrupt pin (18) goes from 5.011 to 5.007 when the relays are running. I tried the internal pullups but it didn't help, and the voltage is OK. The code looks OK. None of the things I tried had any positive effect. Why is the interrupt pin calling the handler function as I turn on some relays when the voltage on the interrupt pin is seemingly stable? any advice? any troubleshooting ideas?
Update
I cycled the power to the power supplies and the arduino USB power maintained power to the system, and the voltage dips did not affect the interrupt. so it's not voltage.
I pulled the electro-mechanical relays, that were being turned on by the 6 relay shield, and when the 6 relays shield relays are cycled without the electro mechanical relays present the interrupt is not called. It's something to do with the electromechanical relays under the relay shield. Any ideas are welcome.
Update 2
For sure it's the electromechanical relays. When they are removed from the socket, the interrupt circuit works as intended. The odd thing is that the Arduino is not really related to the relays. The relays are switching 12V power. There is no relation to 5V inputs or outputs. Any thoughts? any stabs in the dark I can investigate are really appreciated.

An impressive installation there! That looks like a hall effect flow meter. Is it physically distant from the relays and other sources of magnetic interference? With a hall effect sensor, "bouncing" should not be a problem as it would with mechanical contacts. FALLING appears to br the correct  edge to trigger the ISR and the external 10k pullup appears OK. Nothing else is using pin18 via a shield or otherwise?

This looks like an electrical noise issue due to relay chatter. Have a look here for what electrical noise looks like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nj-Q8FQxHhU I suspect the relay does something to the 12V power supplies, that then do something to the 3.3v and 5V power supplies that cause the issue. Electrical noise and relays... seems like the culprit.

@6v6gt thanks. 100% the issue is relay related, and I don't think it's the magnetism from the relay affecting the hall sensor. It looks like the operation of the relays are causing noise in the system, which is being caught by the interrupt circuit. I think this is a question for electrical stack exchange

OK. If you are also using naked relays (as opposed to modules which would anyway have them) ensure there is a flyback diode across each coil. Also look at snubber circuits on the output side of the relays especially if they are switching main voltage into an inductive load.

@6v6gt if you could please provide your comment as an expanded answer I will gladly try it, and likely accept, as it looks right. Is flyback diode something I buy? what is a snubber circuit? The 12V the relays are switching is powering a motorized ball valve. My electronics is pretty weak...

I won't do it as a formal answer because this is straying outside the bounds of an "Arduino" issue (and I risk losing some Brownie points if it is marked down). It may be that what you have described as electromechanical relays does not have a flyback diode across the coil. This can be a normal 1n4007 diode. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode . Here is an example of a snubber https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/193580835405 . Otherwise Google for relay snubber.

@6v6gt The internet is great because there are people like you. I happened to have the 1n4007, I put it as a 'flyback' on all my relay coils, and voila! fixed! Everything works! Thank you so much!

Electrical noise strikes again! A really good explanation of electrical noise can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nj-Q8FQxHhU
Once I narrowed the issue to the electromechanical relays, since they were not connected to any of the Arduino power (3.3v, and 5v) I realized that some sort of electrical interference is happening. Some sort of electrical phenomena was causing the interrupt pin to 'malfunction' aka not behave as expected. I followed the advice for a 'flyback' relay (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) where I simply put a 1n4007 diode across the relay coil, and BOOM! no more issue on the interrupt pin.
This may seem inappropriate for an Arduino page, but I would argue that this is indeed an Arduino issue as Arduino is both software AND hardware, and since this may help someone else with an Arduino, this belongs here.
A big thanks to @6v6gt. You rock!
